# Merge [decentralized-applications] and [dapp]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Would it be appropriate to merge [decentralized-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decentralized-applications) and [dapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dapp)? [dapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dapp) does not have an info page but the questions appear to be related to "decentralized applications" aka "dApps".

Comment: Not a subject-matter expert here, but makes sense to me. By the way, strange to see a staff member make a post like this! Nothing wrong with...just unexpected! :)

Comment: Yes, merge and keep the more verbose name.  Like @richardec I have no expertise in the subject, though, but I think `[dapp]` is a useless tag.

Comment: Has someone actually looked through all of the questions currently tagged [[tag:dapp]] and verified that they all refer to "decentralized applications"? If not, we should clean up those specific questions before doing the merge, when it's easier to find them. (As always with tagging requests, actual usage matters much more than what happens to appear in the tag wiki/info page.)

Comment: @CodyGray I had a look through all the 89 questions, and they're all related to decentralized applications and web3 development. Unless I missed something. Though going by the titles alone everything is at least related to blockchains. There is a [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71493968/how-crypto-token-in-metamask-wallet-get-stolen-by-hacker) that is off-topic and not related to programming, just to smart contracts in general.